# Eclipse not able to clean a Android project saying missing gen folder

Tags: android

Whenever I am trying to clean a android project, I am getting a error in eclipse saying the gen folder in missing.

Whereas the gen folder is created only after the building the project which eclipse is not allowing me to do.

Comment: Have you updated ADT plugin ?

Comment: Please check your 'res' folder with xml file in it.ie.strings.xml,main.xml or any other xml file.or images with (a-z,_,1-10)names only.your problem will 100 % solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution.

There was problem with the Java compiler version.

Eclipse was taking J2SE 1.5 as the default which was not creating the "gen" folder.

I changed the Java compiler version to 1.6.

Now the "gen" folder is getting generated and it is working fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Package Explorer -> Right click the project -> "Android Tools" -> "Fix Project Properties"
Project -> Clean
```

If this doesn't work. 
Try deleting the project from workspace.
And use import "Import existing code into workspace"

Comment: Tried the above methods. Did not help.

Comment: Did you use "Import existing code" or "Import existing project" ?

Comment: Yes Shakti, I used "import existing project"

Comment: I got the solution of the problem. Please see in the below answer.

Comment: "Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties" should have done that automatically ! Not sure why it didn't work for you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like eclipse is making life hard for you.

Here a few things you could try :

1. Restart eclipse
2. Fix Project properties
3. Remove the project from the workspace and import it again
4. Make sure there are no errors in your XML files
5. Select "build automatically"